# Can't find neo4j-rest-graphdb artifact on Maven?

Tags: maven, neo4j

I added this to my maven but it says it can't find this dependency. Very strange! What's the problem?

```
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.neo4j/neo4j-rest-graphdb -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-rest-graphdb</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: simple answer is that this artifacts are not in maven central. You should take a look into the docs of Neo4J where to find those artifacts. They have their own hosted repository.

Answer (score 1):

This deps is in the `http://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/` repository, not in central, so you should add it like this in your `pom.xml`:

```
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>spring-repo</id>
    <url>http://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>
```

Comment: It's strange. If it's not at Maven central, why is it shown here:?https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.neo4j/neo4j-rest-graphdb/2.0.1

Comment: Have you read the note : `this artifact it located at Spring Plugins repository (http://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/) ` ?

Comment: Yes, I missed that note! I am currently testing "jersey-client" to use the REST api.  Do you recommend "neo4j-rest-graphdb" over "jersey-client" to use Neo4j's Restful service?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like (at least now) version 2.0.1 is not present in http://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/ officialy mentioned on https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.neo4j/neo4j-rest-graphdb/2.0.1.

You can still use neo4j maven repositories:

```
<repositories>
(...)
    <repository>
        <id>neo4j-release-repository</id>
        <name>Neo4j Maven 2 release repository</name>
        <url>http://m2.neo4j.org/content/repositories/releases/</url>
    </repository>
(...)
</repositories>
```